# How to count the occurrences of a string in mysql

Tags: mysql, regex, count, sum

I have a database view (viewAll) containing these columns:

Locus, varchar(10)
MismatchDesc, varchar(200)

This table could look like:

```
Locus MismatchDesc
HLA-A 435delA;553insG
HLA-B 665subA;776subA;998delG 
HLA-B 776subA;998delG
HLA-B 998delG
HLA-A 553insG
```

I need to produce a view with additional column *MismatchCount* So that it looks like:

```
Locus MismatchDesc MismatchCount
HLA-A 435delA;553insG 1
HLA-B 665subA;776subA;998delG 1 
HLA-B 776subA;998delG 1
HLA-B 998delG 3
HLA-A 553insG 2
```

Currently I have:

```
CREATE VIEW mismatchCount AS SELECT Locus, MismatchDesc, SUM(IF('%'+MismatchDesc+'%',1,0)) AS MismatchCount FROM viewAll GROUP BY MismatchDescGDNA ORDER BY mismatchCount ASC;
```

I had hoped it would produce my required output using sneaky wildcards and the sum function, but it is not, it is simply producing an output in a more complicated way than had I just used 'count'.

So this currently produces output:

```
Locus MismatchDesc MismatchCount
HLA-A 435delA;553insG 1 
HLA-B 665subA;776subA;998delG 1 
HLA-B 776subA;998delG 1
HLA-B 998delG 1
HLA-A 553insG 1
```

Somewhere out there, there must be a way to count the occurrence of each string, and each instance matching a string?

I cannot separate the strings, which are semi colon separated because I need to count each unique string instance as a whole also. I hope this makes sense.

EDIT

I am not limited to my way of performing the query, if there is a more effective and quicker way, please share, because this is to process a huge amount of data, and therefore likely very slow.

Comment: How do you define "mismatch"?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, SO was not allowing me to comment due to low rep. The mismatch is either a coordinate followed by in|del|sub and then A|C|T|G+  or a list of these separated by semi-colons @RickJames. AS explained in question, these are VARCHARS of up to 200 characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a correlated query to get the matching count for each Locus like this:

```
CREATE VIEW mismatchCount AS
SELECT s.Locus,
       s.MismatchDesc,
       (select count(*) from YourTable t
       WHERE t.MismatchDesc like concat('%',s.mismatchDesc,'%') as MismatchCount
FROM YourTable s
```

Or with a join:

```
CREATE VIEW mismatchCount AS
SELECT s.Locus,
       s.MismatchDesc,
       count(case when t.MismatchDesc like concat('%',s.mismatchDesc,'%') then 1 end) as MismatchCount
FROM YourTable s
INNER JOIN YourTable t ON(1=1)
GROUP BY s.locus,s.mismatchDesc
```

Comment: Thank you for your response @Yossi, I have been attempting to incorporate your query, it looks like it is what I want, but it appears to be very slow/memory intensive with my server and database, so it is yet untested while I configure the memory use and create a subset of my data

Comment: You can also achieve this goal with a join instead of the correlated query.. If you want the solution tell me and I'll update the answer, I'll appreciate you accepting my answer if it helped you @CG3

Comment: I will accept once I know if it has helped me/I can test it. Would a join be a less memory intensive way of completing this query? Thanks @Yossi

Comment: This method is too memory intensive, and taking too long/not completing, would you be able to update with your join solution so that I may see if it is quicker @Yossi?

Comment: Thank you for your help @Yossi. I am afraid my data is too large for the queries, but I doubt there is fault in your answers (except a missing close bracket in first attempt), so will accept as answer.